# How to solve the most general 3 by 3 symmetrix matrix for its eigen values and eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-equations

am trying to get eigen values and eigen vectors of a (general) $3\times3$ symmetric matrix with real entries as matrix elements. Is there any closed form for the eigen vectors and eigen values. Assuming the entries in the matrix are real.

Comment: The eigenvalues of a matrix $A$ are the roots of the polynomial $p_A(t) = \det(t I - A)$. For $3 \times 3$ $A$, $p_A(t)$ is cubic, for which a closed but unwieldy general formula is available.

Comment: @user135580: Try this [*WA Link*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=eigensystem+%7B%7Ba,b,c%7D,%7Bb,d,e%7D,%7Bc,e,f%7D%7D)

Comment: You can certainly arrive at such a formula for the eigenvalues directly from the definition as the characteristic polynomial will be a cubic. Since the cubic equation has a formula and the determinant function has a formula you can compose them to solve the overall equation.

Comment: @Moo Wow.  I knew the cubic formula was ugly,  but adding that with a generic 3x3 matrix...wow.

Comment: @Alan: I would even say I was surprised that it converged to that very long and **ugly** result!

Comment: Is it really possible to solve for eigen vectors...assuming there are three real eigen values $$\lambda_{1},\lambda_{2} ,\lambda_{3}$$. Is it possible to arrive at an expression for components of each eigen vector with this assumption for that general symmetric matrix

Comment: Yes - the link I provided shows both eigenvalues and eigenvectors.